# How to cover rawl plugs in plasterboard?

Tags: drywall, painting, plaster

I am not at all versed with DIY but am assuming these are rawlplugs on plasterboard?

The brick is very crumbly so I am worried about removing the plugs.

I cant really afford to hire a plasterer and am hoping there might be an acceptable way of covering/flattening these before repainting.

Many thanks for your help

[image: 1]

[image: Pic 2 of wall]

[image: Pic 3 of wall]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried sanding one down?

Answer (score 3):

Photos show "nail pops," which indicate poor quality drywall installation combined with movement of the structure. DIY remedy usually entails driving a drywall screw adjacent to the pop, digging out the pop with a knife, and spackling both the screw head and the divot to a level surface before repainting.